# Continuity on a subset vs continuity on a subspace.

Tags: general-topology, continuity, metric-spaces, uniform-continuity

Suppose $f:X\to Y$ is a function between two metric spaces such that $f:X\to Y$ is continuous on $A$ i.e. at each point of $A$.But is this equivalent to saying $f|_A:A\to Y$ is continuous between the two metric spaces $A$ and $Y$.The forward part is true because if $f$ is continuous on $A$,then $f|_A$ is continuous map between $A$ and $Y$.But Suppose $f|_A$ is continuous map between $A$ and $Y$ metric space.This does not imply the first one.For example $f(x)=0$ if $x\neq 0$ and $f(0)=1$,it is not continuous at $0$ ,so $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is not continuous on $\{0\}$,because it is not continuous at every point of $\{0\}$.But $f|_{\{0\}}:\{0\}\to \mathbb R$ is continuous map from $\{0\}$ to $\mathbb R$.Does this example work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your example works.

$f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is not continuous on $\{0\}$ since

$$\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)=0 \neq 1 = f(0)$$

But the resticted map $f\vert_{\{0\}}$ is continuous, for example because it is constant.

So the two statements are not equivalent.

Comment: So we should be careful while using the two similar looking phrases.

Comment: how could $f|_{\mathbb R-\{0\}}$ work because $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is also continuous on $\mathbb R-\{0\}$i.e. at each point of it?

Comment: @ ε-δ please see my question properly,I am looking for a function $f:X\to Y$ that is not continuous on $A$ but $f|_A:A\to Y$ is a continuous map between $A$ and $Y$.But here you map fails to be discontinuous at on $\mathbb R-\{0\} \subset \mathbb R$ when you consider the map from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @ ε-δ consider the example I gave here,$f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is not continuous on $A=\{0\}$ but $f|_A: A \to \mathbb R$ is a continuous map between the metric spaces $A$ and $\mathbb R$.It matters about which metric space we are talking.I think you are confused with the phrase when I say $f:X\to Y$ is continuous on $A$,it simply means $f:X\to Y$ is continuous at each point of $A$.which of course implies $f|_A:A\to Y$ is a continuous map between $A$ and $Y$ metric spaces but not conversely as you can see in the above example.

Comment: @can u delete the above conversation because you ve changed the answer,so others will not bee able to understand what is this conv about?

Comment: I did, but you have to delete your own comments yourself.